# jsp Redirect not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm sending a response for a particular URL using the below servlet code.

```
public class CasRedirectServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws IOException, ServletException{
        System.out.println("CasRedirectServlet Called == " + TbuyHelper.getDashboardLocation());
        RequestDispatcher rd = req
                .getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");
        rd.include(req, res);
    }
```

Code for test.jsp

```
<%@ page import="tbuy.tbuyHelp"%>

<% response.sendRedirect("banana/index.html#/dashboard/file/tbuy.json"); %>
```

Now, I see a blank test.jsp being displayed..

The response.sendredirect to the given URL is not working.

Comment: it's a weird url in your jsp... have you tried to inspect using firebug's network tab?

Comment: You must use `forward` instead of `include`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per doc of RequestDispatcher.include method

> The included servlet cannot change the response status code or set
>   headers; any attempt to make a change is ignored.

response.sendRedirect works by sending a 302 status and location header. So your redirect in test.jsp is ignored

EDIT:
Take a look at forward method, it may be more appropriate than include.